# Handle a kill signal

Tags: c, linux, signals

I want to handle a `kill signal` from C program.
I'm starting by create an infinite loop and handle the signal

```
void signal_callback_handler(int signum)
{
   printf("Caught signal %d\n",signum);
   // Cleanup and close up stuff here

   // Terminate program
   exit(signum);
}
 main()
{
    signal(SIGINT, signal_callback_handler);
    printf("pid: %d \n",getpid());
    while(1)
    {

    }

}
```

When I run this program and make CTRL+C, the kill is handled, and it works. The message `Caught signal` is printed.
However, when I'm trying to kill from another program

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    kill(atoi(argv[1]), SIGKILL);

    return 0;

}
```

The program is stoped but the signal is not handled. In other words, the message `Caught signal` is not printed. The infinite loop is just stopped.

Comment: Change `SIGKILL` to `SIGINT` and it should work. It is, very much on purpose, not possible to catch `SIGKILL`.

Comment: SIGKILL is a last resort

Comment: This `kill(atoi(argv[1]), ...` is danger seeking code ... *shudder*

Comment: Yes It works. Thank you

Comment: Signal handlers must not call any functions that are not async-signal-safe.  In particular, they must not call `printf()` or `exit()` (though they may call `_Exit()` or its POSIX-specified equivalent, `_exit()`).

Comment: Voting to close this as a typo...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is it: **you cannot catch a `SIGKILL`**, it will *definitely* kill your program, this is what it's been created for.

Comment: Well, you can catch it, but not "stop it". It'll slip out of your hands again.

Comment: Even if you could catch it, his first program only has a handler for `SIGINT`, not `SIGKILL`.

Comment: @alk No, you can't even catch it. SIGKILL and SIGSTOP will always immediately kill or stop a process, respectively. The signal handler is never called.

Comment: @duskwuff: Yes, sure; I stand corrected, confused it with `SIGSEGV` :}.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot catch or ignore a SIGKILL signal. Also in your code shown below you have created a signal handler only for SIGINT, that is, whenever a SIGINT signal is caught it will call the signal_callback_handler(). All other signals will be caught by the default signal handler.

```
signal(SIGINT, signal_callback_handler);
```

For example if you want to catch a SIGHUP signal also in the your program you need to define a signal handler as below:

```
signal(SIGHUP, signal_callback_handler);
```

Modified code is shown below:

```
void signal_callback_handler(int signum)
{   if (signum == SIGINT){
        printf("Caught signal %d\n",signum);
         //Do the action need to be taken when SIGINT is received 
     }
     else if(signum == SIGHUP){
        printf("Caught signal %d\n",signum);
        //Do the action need to be taken when SIGHUP is received
        
     }
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGINT, signal_callback_handler);
    signal(SIGHUP, signal_callback_handler);
    printf("pid: %d \n",getpid());
    while(1)
    {

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
signal(SIGTERM, signal_callback_handler);
```

As you are only connected to SIGINT (e.g. Ctrl+C) but for a kill/killall your friend is SIGTERM